# How do I run a SQL query against 2 views that are linked by an ID but has different column names?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, view

I currently have 2 views that house some data.

View1: includes patientsPID and their billing/invoice information (high-level)

View2: includes patientsCID and their respective line items for their billing invoice information (granularity of View1)

I am trying to run a query where I will be able to validate some data. E.g. -> I want to see patientsPID = 1 and see the total amount paid and join it to View2 to see in more details on the invoice.

[expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55QKe.png)

Thank you.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: thank you. I have updated my question with an image attached to show exactly what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join `View1` and `View2`:

```
select v1.patientspid, v1.invoiceheader, v2.invoiceline, v2.amount
from view1 v1 inner join view2 v2
on v1.patientspid = v2.patientscid
order by v1.patientspid
```

If you want to get the results for a patientspid use

```
where v1.patientspid = 1
```

and no `order by`

Answer (score 0):

In this case both PatientsPID and PatientsCID act as your Key. The column names don't have to be the same as long as the data contained in them are linked (Same Data).

```
Select View1.PatientsPID, View1.AmountPaid, View2.[SomeColumnName]
From View1 inner join View2 on View1.PatientsPID = View2.PatientsCID
Where View1.PatientsPID = 1
```

Use Join in the From line and you have to set which columns are equal between the two tables. These columns have to contain the same data in order to be able to link. Whatever column names you want to select just place the table name in front of it as show above, this prevents errors in the event of an ambiguous column name

Comment: thank you for the clarification. lets say for an example I had a third view, would I just do the same, where I would create another/separate inner join clause and join it with the matching column from a different view? Thanks.

Comment: Thats right, From View1 inner join View2 on View1.PatientsPID = View2.PatientsCID inner join View3 on view2.PatientsCID = View3.[Column]